# Ignore method params within with closure call.

Tags: groovy

I have a class like this:

```
class Test
{
    def method(def args)
    {
        println args
    }
}
```

And I do:

```
def test = new Test()
test.with{
    method([1:1])
}
```

which works as expected. But what I want is to call `method` without params, if I do:

```
method [1:1]
```

I get the following error:

```
You tried to use a map entry for an index operation, this is not allowed. Maybe something should be set in parentheses or a comma is missing?
 at line: 13, column: 13
```

Are there I can call the method without params? Is that possible?

Comment: How do you say you are calling `method` without params?

Answer (score 1):

Without parenthesis, it treats as if you are accessing a list element by its index.

```
method [1:1] --> method[1:1]
```

and complains about the index not being a number but a map entry. So you can try:

```
test.with{
    def map = [1:1]
    method map

    //or just
    method 1:1
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. but I am still confused with the question.